# Java Webservices Send the CSV file attachment as Response

Tags: java, web-services

I want to send the CSV File as attachment in Java Webservices Response.
   Can this be done. Please provide the steps if it is possible

Comment: I don't know you, but I've tried google here. :-) so far, I could find http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/webservice-attachments/README.html, http://www.coderanch.com/t/491348/Web-Services/java/Adding-attachments-web-service-response and http://wso2.com/library/1675/ :-)

Comment: Are you talking about a soap web-service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [`Content-Disposition`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html) header on the response. For example, the headers:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.csv"
```

...will cause a browser to download the HTTP response entity as a file named "filename.csv". You probably want a MIME type too, which will look like this:

```
Content-Type: application/csv
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.csv"
```

Comment: Hi Can you please provide me the sample code that would help me. I am new to Jave Webservices. Thanks.